# [ASP.NET C#]Displaying only one record using filter in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi i'm having a problem to search with 2 value like the semester and schoolyear it only gives me one record while I have at least 30 records found.

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conn))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT *FROM tblEvaluation WHERE Semester LIKE '%' + @sem +  '%' and SchoolYear like '%' + @sy +  '%'";
                cmd.Connection = sqlcon;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sem", DropDownList1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sy", DropDownList2.Text);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What happens when you run the same SQL, with 2 parameters directly?

Comment: it only display one record. i found out that the CMD.parameters only detect 2 counts. it only reads the first record.

Comment: this sounds like you are not using the SQL Wild Card `%` properly. there is a difference with name Like `ABC%` vs name Like `%ABC` vs name Like `%ABC%` please understand the differences and try them out in your exact use case / scenario

Comment: @MethodMan i already try those and still getting the same result.

Comment: try messing around with the code in SQL Management Studio's sounds like you have an issue with how you are doing your Where Clause. have you tried doing it with an OR instead to see if it returns the correct information.

Comment: Could it be that `AddWithValue` causes some trouble? You could try with `Add`. See: http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/.

Comment: Im the dumbest person on earth there is nothing wrong with the code, the problem is my database i forgot that ive erased it and replaced a new one which only one data @ 2nd semester 2016-2017, i think i need to sleep now. and by the way thank you for the quick response.